# Moving files with batch files from one pc to a server, to a another pc - worried about disk corruption

Tags: corruption, batch-processing

I use scheduled tasks that calls a batch file, that calls more batch files to move about three files from a pc, to a server, then to multiple other pcs.  It all happens very quickly, as they are small files.

Are there any pitfalls for how fast these transfers happen?  I'm just mildly concerned about causing some disk corruption somehow.

I use logic like 
1.
Call MapToPc
if files exist then move file to folder on server.
Disconnect

2.
Call SendtoPCs
If files exist (the files just moved to the server) then MapToPCs
Move all files
Disconnect

All of this happens in about 2 secs or less.

edit: this on windows 7, server 2003, xp respectively

Comment: Robocopy is great tool to copy files : log, retry and much more options. Free from Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any pitfalls for how fast these transfers happen?

No.

If copying around files causes filesystem corruption, you have other issues.

Of course, make sure you have a good backup system, and that you **test** regularly.

Comment: I was going to add the concern of the validity of the data itself. If he's using the regular copy function, something like robocopy might help fill a void?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My question really revolves around the use of batch files and if they inherently have risk to the file systems.   I'm actually using mostly a "move" command for the first step, then "copy" for the final step.  robocopy is a good call too.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate a hash (say md5sum) of the file, and then send that along for the recipient server to verify. This is a standard way of verifying the file integrity, if you are concerned.